# Uniqueness of matrix logarithm

Tags: matrices, analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

I refer to the following theorem:

[image]

from 'Formal Power Series and Linear Systems of Meromorphic Ordinary Differential Equations' by Werner Balser.

I can see that any matrices $M$ satisfying $\exp(2 \pi i M) = C$ whose eigenvalues have real parts contained in $[0,1)$ must be unique up to similarity, essentially through Jordan form considerations.

However I do not know how to go from this, or the result stated before the final uniqueness part of the theorem in the attached image, namely 'The eigenvalues of any two such $M$ can only differ by integers', which I do see must be true, to the statement that there is really a unique matrix $M$ whose eigenvalues are in the strip $0 \leq \text{Re}(z) < 1$ with $\exp(2 \pi i M) = C$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: To support that claim imagine $C$ and $M$ to be diagonal. Then $\exp(2\pi i m_i)=c_i$ for every diagonal element. The left hand side is periodic in $m_i$.

Comment: Yes that is fine, if the claim was only talking about the possible $M$'s being diagonal or even more generally being in Jordan Normal Form, then immediately we would get uniqueness. I'm fine with everything in the claim besides the very last uniqueness statement for general (not necessarily diagonal or Jordan form) $M$ and $C$

Comment: The Theorem is much more general and makes the claim for any invertible matrix $C$. I had the impression that the simple special case was of any help. Apparently it wasn't.

Comment: Not at all, thank you for your contribution, I'm inclined to believe that the eigenvalue restraint is going to enforce that given $V = TK$, where $T J' T^{-1} = E$ and $V J' V^{-1} = F$ are two matrix logs (or more precisely $2 \pi i$ times each of them are matrix logs) of $C$ with the same JNF $J'$ having eigenvalues with real part in $[0,1)$, and $K$ commutes with $J$, where $J$ is the JNF of $C$, then $K$ must also commute with $J'$. I believe if this turns out to be true (under the eigenvalue constraint), then we are home.